# I want to know list of methods of predefined classes in objective-c

Tags: iphone

I want to know list of methods of predefined classes in objective-c using any tool like "javap" in java.

In java, javap tool is used for getting list of all existing methods of class using command prompt.

Is it possible in objective-c? any tools are available?

Please help me.

Thank U.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the objc runtime function `class_copyMethodList`, then enumerate the results for the info you are interested in.